# Copy MYSQL with innoDB to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database, cron, innodb, myisam

I have a little issue with a mysql table with innoDB engine (from an inventory system). The table has several million records and I want to programm a little reporting tool which is using this table. As the engine is innoDB the select query is veeeery slow.
So I copied the table to a new db and changed the engine to myisam manually. Now the query only takes about 50ms and not 7s as before.

Now, what I want to do is write a little cronjob which copies the table every night from the inventory system db to a new database and changes the engine from innodb to myisam.
Is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: You may want to create a data warehouse system that has a replica of the master and is tuned differently. InnoDB is slow if you're using MySQL defaults, but it performs significantly better if you've allocated more memory to it. What version of MySQL are you using? What server settings have you applied? You really do not want to flip an important table to MyISAM, **especially** not an inventory system.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot change anything about the inventory system database or the server it's running on. The current mysql version is 5.6.12. The innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 1073741824

Comment: Just for the understanding I did not change the engine of the inventory system table but I made a dump of the table imported it in a new database on another server and changed that engine to myisam and that was working just fine for what I want to do. But as I have only little knowledge of databases thats a quite difficult solution.

Comment: Your buffer is only 107MB?

Comment: Ok I just setup a local Database and allocated about 6gb to it and copied some tables from the orignal system. Now it runs way better.
So I will see if I can configurate a few more things

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default storage engine for a database, but you can change it for the whole server using the default-storage-engine config setting. Note that this will not actually change the storage engine for existing tables though, just for new ones created after the change.